# Subida de archivos codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Esta es la vista:

```
    <div class="row">
<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url('profile/edit/'.$averias_detail['id'])); ?>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">DATOS DE LA AVERÍA</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <!-- form start -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nro_averia" class="control-label">Número de Avería</label>
          <input type="text" name="nro_averia" class="form-control" id="nro_averia" placeholder="" value="<?= $averias_detail['nro_averia']; ?>" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fecha" class="control-label">Fecha</label>
          <input type="text" name="fecha" class="form-control datepicker" id="fecha" value="<?= date('d-m-Y', strtotime(($averias_detail['fecha']))) ; ?>" placeholder="" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="hora" class="control-label">Hora</label>
          <input type="text" name="hora" class="form-control timepicker" id="hora" value="<?= $averias_detail['hora']; ?>" placeholder="" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tel_contacto" class="control-label">Persona de Contacto</label>
          <input type="text" name="tel_contacto" class="form-control" id="tel_contacto" value="<?= $averias_detail['tel_contacto']; ?>" placeholder="" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lugar_averia" class="control-label">Lugar de la Avería</label><br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="lugar_averia" value="Entrada" class="minimal" <?php if($averias_detail['lugar_averia'] == 'Entrada'){echo 'checked';} else{echo '';} ?>>
              Entrada
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="lugar_averia" value="Salida" class="minimal" <?php if($averias_detail['lugar_averia'] == 'Salida'){echo 'checked';} else{echo '';} ?>>
              Salida
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="lugar_averia" value="Pupitre" class="minimal" <?php if($averias_detail['lugar_averia'] == 'Pupitre'){echo 'checked';} else{echo '';} ?>>
              Pupitre
            </label>
             <label>
              <input type="radio" name="lugar_averia" value="Otros" class="minimal" <?php if($averias_detail['lugar_averia'] == 'Otros'){echo 'checked';} else{echo '';} ?>>
              Otros
            </label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descripcion_averia" class="control-label">Descripción de la Avería</label>
            <textarea name="descripcion_averia" class="form-control" id="descripcion_averia" rows="4" placeholder="" readonly><?= $averias_detail['descripcion_averia']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="observaciones" class="control-label">Observaciones del Técnico</label>
            <textarea name="observaciones" class="form-control" id="observaciones" rows="10" placeholder=""><?= $averias_detail['observaciones']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
     </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
  </div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">PARTES DE TRABAJO</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Parte 1</th>
          </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="item">
              <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <?php if(!empty($error)):
            echo '<span class="alert alert-danger" style="display: block;">';
             foreach ($error as $item => $value):?>
                <?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?>
        <?php endforeach; echo '</span>'; endif; ?>

           <span id="filename">Seleccionar un fichero</span>
                        <label for="file-upload">Examinar<input type="file" name="userfile" id="file-upload"></label>
            <p><small class="text-success">Ficheros permitidos: gif, jpg, png, jpeg, pdf - (2MB Máx.)</small></p>


        <?php if(($averias_detail['documento'])==""){ echo 'No hay parte de trabajo adjunto'; } else {?>
                    <?php echo 'Archivo Actual: '.$averias_detail['documento'];} ?>   
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Parte 2</th>
          </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="item">
             <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <?php if(!empty($error2)):
            echo '<span class="alert alert-danger" style="display: block;">';
             foreach ($error2 as $item => $value):?>
                <?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?>
        <?php endforeach; echo '</span>'; endif; ?>

           <span id="filename2">Seleccionar un fichero</span>
                        <label for="file-upload2">Examinar<input type="file" name="userfile2" id="file-upload2"></label>
            <p><small class="text-success">Ficheros permitidos: gif, jpg, png, jpeg, pdf - (2MB Máx.)</small></p>


        <?php if(($averias_detail['documento2'])==""){ echo 'No hay parte de trabajo adjunto'; } else {?>
                    <?php echo 'Archivo Actual: '.$averias_detail['documento2'];} ?>   
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Parte 3</th>
          </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="item">
             <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <?php if(!empty($error3)):
            echo '<span class="alert alert-danger" style="display: block;">';
             foreach ($error3 as $item => $value):?>
                <?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?>
        <?php endforeach; echo '</span>'; endif; ?>

           <span id="filename3">Seleccionar un fichero</span>
                        <label for="file-upload3">Examinar<input type="file" name="userfile3" id="file-upload3"></label>
            <p><small class="text-success">Ficheros permitidos: gif, jpg, png, jpeg, pdf - (2MB Máx.)</small></p>


        <?php if(($averias_detail['documento3'])==""){ echo 'No hay parte de trabajo adjunto'; } else {?>
                    <?php echo 'Archivo Actual: '.$averias_detail['documento3'];} ?>   
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Tengo el siguiente código para subir 3 archivos por separados, no subida multiple, es en codeigniter pero solo me ejecuta el primer if y se sube bien y hace todo correcto con el primer archivo, los otros if de los siguientes archivos no me los ejecuta.

Este es el controlador:

```
    if($this->input->post('submit')){

                if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))  { 

                           $config = array(
                'upload_path' => "./uploads/averias/partes/1/",
                'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                'max_height' => "1200",
                'max_width' => "1900"
                );
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                            if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
                                    $datafiles = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                                    $eliminararchivo = $this->user_model->obtener_doc($id);
                                    unlink("./uploads/averias/partes/1/".$eliminararchivo->documento);

                                    $data['averias_data'] = array(                      
                    'lugar_averia' => $this->input->post('lugar_averia'),                       
                    'documento' => $datafiles['upload_data']['file_name'],
                                            'observaciones' => $this->input->post('observaciones'),
                                         );

                $averias_data = $this->security->xss_clean($data['averias_data']);

                $result = $this->user_model->update_averias($averias_data, $id);

                                   if($result){                                               
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Avería actualizada correctamente');                                                                 
                    redirect(base_url('profile/edit/'.$id));       

                }  


                            } 

                } elseif (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){
                                $nombrearchivo = $this->user_model->obtener_doc($id);

                                $data['averias_data'] = array(

                    'lugar_averia' => $this->input->post('lugar_averia'),
                    'documento' => $nombrearchivo->documento, 
                                            'observaciones' => $this->input->post('observaciones'),
                                         );

                $averias_data = $this->security->xss_clean($data['averias_data']);

                $result = $this->user_model->update_averias($averias_data, $id);


                                  if($result){                                               
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Avería actualizada correctamente');                                                                 
                    redirect(base_url('profile/edit/'.$id));       

                }  


                            } else {
                                $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                                $data['averias_detail'] = $this->user_model->get_averias_by_id($id);
                                $data['title'] = 'Editar Avería';
                                $data['view'] = 'user/averias/averias_edit';
                                $this->load->view('layout', $data);
                            }

                if (!empty($_FILES['userfile2']['name']))  { 

                            $config2 = array(
                'upload_path' => "./uploads/averias/partes/2/",
                'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                'max_height' => "1200",
                'max_width' => "1900"
                );
            $this->load->library('upload', $config2);

                            if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile2')){
                                    $datafiles2 = array('upload_data2' => $this->upload->data());
                                    $eliminararchivo2 = $this->user_model->obtener_doc($id);
                                    unlink("./uploads/averias/partes/2/".$eliminararchivo2->documento2);

                                    $data['averias_data'] = array(                      
                    'lugar_averia' => $this->input->post('lugar_averia'),
                    'documento2' => $datafiles2['upload_data2']['file_name'],
                                            'observaciones' => $this->input->post('observaciones'),
                                         );

                $averias_data = $this->security->xss_clean($data['averias_data']);

                $result = $this->user_model->update_averias($averias_data, $id);


                                    if($result){                                               
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Avería actualizada correctamente');                                                                 
                    redirect(base_url('profile/edit/'.$id));       

                }                                       

                                }             

                }elseif ((empty($_FILES['userfile2']['name']))){
                                $nombrearchivo2 = $this->user_model->obtener_doc($id);

                                $data['averias_data'] = array(

                    'lugar_averia' => $this->input->post('lugar_averia'),
                    'documento2' => $nombrearchivo2->documento2,
                                            'observaciones' => $this->input->post('observaciones'),
                                         );



                $averias_data = $this->security->xss_clean($data['averias_data']);

                $result = $this->user_model->update_averias($averias_data, $id);


                                    if($result){                                               
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Avería actualizada correctamente');                                                                 
                    redirect(base_url('profile/edit/'.$id));       

                }  


                            } else {
                                $data['error2'] = array('error2' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                                $data['averias_detail'] = $this->user_model->get_averias_by_id($id);
                                $data['title'] = 'Editar Avería';
                                $data['view'] = 'user/averias/averias_edit';
                                $this->load->view('layout', $data);
                            } 


                if (!empty($_FILES['userfile3']['name']))  { 

                            $config3 = array(
                'upload_path' => "./uploads/averias/partes/3/",
                'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                'max_height' => "1200",
                'max_width' => "1900"
                );
            $this->load->library('upload', $config3);

                            if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile3')){
                                    $datafiles3 = array('upload_data3' => $this->upload->data());
                                    $eliminararchivo3 = $this->user_model->obtener_doc($id);
                                    unlink("./uploads/averias/partes/3/".$eliminararchivo3->documento3);

                                    $data['averias_data'] = array(                      
                    'lugar_averia' => $this->input->post('lugar_averia'),
                    'documento3' => $datafiles3['upload_data3']['file_name'],
                                            'observaciones' => $this->input->post('observaciones'),
                                         );

                $averias_data = $this->security->xss_clean($data['averias_data']);

                $result = $this->user_model->update_averias($averias_data, $id);


                                    if($result){                                               
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Avería actualizada correctamente');                                                                 
                    redirect(base_url('profile/edit/'.$id));       

                }                                       

                                }             

                }elseif ((empty($_FILES['userfile3']['name']))){
                                $nombrearchivo3 = $this->user_model->obtener_doc($id);

                                $data['averias_data'] = array(

                    'lugar_averia' => $this->input->post('lugar_averia'),
                    'documento3' => $nombrearchivo3->documento3,
                                            'observaciones' => $this->input->post('observaciones'),
                                         );



                $averias_data = $this->security->xss_clean($data['averias_data']);

                $result = $this->user_model->update_averias($averias_data, $id);


                                    if($result){                                               
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Avería actualizada correctamente');                                                                 
                    redirect(base_url('profile/edit/'.$id));       

                }  


                            } else {
                                $data['error3'] = array('error3' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                                $data['averias_detail'] = $this->user_model->get_averias_by_id($id);
                                $data['title'] = 'Editar Avería';
                                $data['view'] = 'user/averias/averias_edit';
                                $this->load->view('layout', $data);
                            }



                   }else{

            $data['averias_detail'] = $this->user_model->get_averias_by_id($id);
            $data['title'] = 'Editar Avería';
            $data['view'] = 'user/averias/averias_edit';
            $this->load->view('layout', $data);
        }
```

Saludos

Comment: Muestra tu formulario en la vista como lo estas implementando

Comment: Ya he puesto la vista, cuando no pongo el elseif me sube los archivos, pero necesito que no valide si el campo esta vacio porque no es obligatorio la subida de todos los archivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas haciendo uso de `elseif` por lo tanto cuando entra a cualquier `if` o `elseif` ya no entra a los demás, tienes que hacer los `if` separados, te dejo un ejemplo de como los recibí yo en un proyecto que realice y justamente requería de 4 imágenes donde no era necesaria la carga de las 4, es bastante claro y es lo que tu estas realizando.

Vista `formulario`:

```
<form id="form" action="<?echo base_url('index/savePost')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="height: 2250px">
    <p class="spaceleft">State:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <select id="selectState" class="select" name="form[state]" size="1" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>
            <?php foreach($States as $State){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $State['id']?>"><?php echo $State['name']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">County:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <select id="selectCounty" class="select" name="form[county]" size="1" disabled required>
            <option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">City:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <select id="selectCity" class="select" name="form[city]" size="1" disabled required>
            <option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">Vehicle Type:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <select id="selectVehicle" class="select" name="form[vehicle]" size="1" disabled required>
            <option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>
            <?php foreach($Vehicles as $Vehicle){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $Vehicle['id'];?>"><?php echo $Vehicle['name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">Action:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <select id="selectAction" class="select" name="form[action]" size="1" disabled required>
            <option value="" disabled selected value>Select One</option>
            <?php foreach($Actions as $Action){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $Action['id'];?>"><?php echo $Action['name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">Title:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <input type="text" id="inputTitle" class="title" name="form[title]" size="21" style=" font-size: 55px; height: 75px; width: 870px;"  required>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">Description:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <textarea id="inputDescription" class="description" name="form[description]" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <p class="spaceleft">Attach Images:</p>
    <div class="centered">
        <input class="space" name="img_1" type="file" id="img_1" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" size="21" style=" font-size: 55px; height: 75px; width: 870px;" required/>
        <input class="space" name="img_2" type="file" id="img_2" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" size="21" style=" font-size: 55px; height: 75px; width: 870px;"/>
        <input class="space" name="img_3" type="file" id="img_3" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" size="21" style=" font-size: 55px; height: 75px; width: 870px;"/>
        <input class="space" name="img_4" type="file" id="img_4" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" size="21" style=" font-size: 55px; height: 75px; width: 870px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="centered">
        <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="centered" hidden="true">
        <input type="text" id="inputLat" class="title" name="form[lat]" size="21" style=" font-size: 55px; height: 75px; width: 870px;"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="centered" hidden="true">
        <input type="text" id="inputLng" class="title" name="form[lng]" size="21" style=" font-size: 55px; height: 75px; width: 870px;"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="centeredlimit">
        <button type="submit" class="auto-style2">
            <img src="<?echo base_url("assets/img/buttons/button_post.jpg");?>" height="120" width="650" >
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controlador `funcion`:

```
public function savePost()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['form'])){
            $form = $_POST['form'];
            if (!empty($_FILES['img_1']['name'])){
                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('img_1')){
                    $img_1 = $this->upload->data();
                }else{
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }
            if (!empty($_FILES['img_2']['name'])){
                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('img_2')){
                    $img_2 = $this->upload->data();
                }else{
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }
            if (!empty($_FILES['img_3']['name'])){
                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('img_3')){
                    $img_3 = $this->upload->data();
                }else{
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }
            if (!empty($_FILES['img_4']['name'])){
                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('img_4')){
                    $img_4 = $this->upload->data();
                }else{
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }

            if(!isset($img_1['file_name'])){$img_1['file_name'] = "";}
            if(!isset($img_2['file_name'])){$img_2['file_name'] = "";}
            if(!isset($img_3['file_name'])){$img_3['file_name'] = "";}
            if(!isset($img_4['file_name'])){$img_4['file_name'] = "";}

            $aData = array(
                'id_state' => $form['state'],
                'id_county' => $form['county'],
                'id_city' => $form['city'],
                'id_vehicle' => $form['vehicle'],
                'id_action' => $form['action'],
                'title' => $form['title'],
                'description' => $form['description'],
                'img_1' => $img_1['file_name'],
                'img_2' => $img_2['file_name'],
                'img_3' => $img_3['file_name'],
                'img_4' => $img_4['file_name'],
                'lat' => $form['lat'],
                'lng' => $form['lng']
            );

            if($id = $this->Index_model->saveAd($aData))
            {
                $data = $aData;
                $data['Id'] = $id;
                $data['Title'] = "Posting Confirmation";
                $this->load->view('posting_confirmation',$data);
            }
        }else{
            redirect('index', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduardo Javier ahora si que me quedo muy claro

Comment: @elyera por nada mucha suerte!